# Unexplained error occured

Tags: magento-1.6, model

I had an extremely strange error occur today when I added

```
$error_message = "error Doing Saasu Order Link";
Mage:log($error_message);
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__($error_message));
```

If I comment out the Mage::log line, it works fine

```
Error comes up with
( ! ) Fatal error: Label 'Mage' already defined in C:\wamp\www\local_wildfire\app\code\local\Wildfiretextbooks\Saasu\Model\Saasuconnect.php on line 849
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0009  380632  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0094  748832  Mage::run( )    ..\index.php:80
3   0.0300  1978136 Mage_Core_Model_App->run( ) ..\Mage.php:640
4   1.2155  9668488 Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch( )  ..\App.php:349
5   1.2459  10954408    Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match( )   ..\Front.php:176
6   1.2576  11581480    Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch( ) ..\Standard.php:250
7   1.4137  14910232    Slink_MageSaasu_Admin_SchedulesController->runAction( ) ..\Action.php:420
8   1.4217  15034424    Slink_MageSaasu_Model_Schedules->run( ) ..\SchedulesController.php:163
9   1.4355  15384808    Inventory->execute( )   ..\Schedules.php:77
10  1.4450  15560200    Mage::getModel( )   ..\Inventory.php:53
11  1.4451  15560320    Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance( ) ..\Mage.php:432
12  1.4451  15560688    class_exists ( )    ..\Config.php:1348
13  1.4451  15561024    Varien_Autoload->autoload( )    ..\Autoload.php:0

The line that it says it crashed on is
10  1.4450  15560200    Mage::getModel( )   ..\Inventory.php:53
$wildfire_sassu_model = Mage::getModel('Wildfiretextbooks_Saasu/Saasuconnect');
```

It does not even call the function where the log is, however, that module is loaded.

Any explanation as to what is happening?

Answer (score 4):

You have a typo:

```
Mage:log($error_message);
```

should be:

```
Mage::log($error_message);
```

Note the extra `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank Jonathan for the good answer!

I want to give a little more context:

A label is used together with goto. Like this:

```
Thanks to http://php.net/goto
goto label;
echo 'Foo';

label:
echo 'Bar';
```

So `goto` changes the flow of the program and let the program go on at the `label`.

Comment: Great explanation. Very esoteric and shows why it was not a compile error.  Thanks a lot